# soft-bricked intex aqua young usb debugging disabled

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, unbricking, flashtool

I bought an *Intex Aqua Young* and got it rooted. I wanted a stronger supersu version app while the existing one was a bit slower in granting root access for the apps – so I uninstalled the present one and installed a new supersu app from the store. Then I rebooted the phone.

But now it hangs on the logo and doesn't boot. I had disabled USB debugging before it got bricked. I have the flashing tools and original firmware, but am unable to flash the device.

I came to know that I can flash through external sd, but how can I convert `.pac` to `.zip` (firmware with `.zip` extention is required to flash through external sd). Firmware is available only as `.pac` file for the model.

Please help me: I want to know if I can convert a firmware file having `.pac` extention into `.zip`? Or is there any other way to unbrick my phone?

Comment: This was [reposted on a recommendation from Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37975350/472495) that Android Enthusiasts would be a better place for it. However, it should have been pointed out that a post of such little effort is probably going to be regarded as off-topic across the whole network, so apologies for lumbering this community with it!

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please don't use "txtspeak" / "SMS lingo" on SE sites, but rather fully spell each word. Many users here are no native English speakers, and some already have a hard enough time to follow normal English. sm frmatng wd also hlp. When you've brought your post into a readable format, it can be reopened for answers. // What you probably did is having your SuperSU controlling system apps at boot (I've seen that option). Flash your ROM again, that should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a pac file, you can use the factory tool called Research Download or Upgrade Download to flash the firmware and you don't even need USB debugging to do that.